# PHPmailer and vanilla JavaScript AJAX form prompt

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer

So, I needed a contact form that can send emails with a "success" prompt that appears in my form, WITHOUT reloading. I have found PHPmailer that helps with sending mail to the inbox and not spam (this alone works fine, email sent straight to inbox). I then add the JS validation then AJAX, then the PHP that deals with the JSON response.

The "success" prompt appears when I click "send" (good!) but the problem is that no email has been sent/received. The code without the AJAX works fine on both my local and web hosts perfectly. How do I optimize this so the success prompt appears and the email is sent (inbox, ideally)?

No jQuery or any extra plugins please.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return doRegister()">
        <input id="mail-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
        <span id="name-alert"></span>
        <input id="mail-email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
        <span id="email-alert"></span>
        <input id="mail-subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject">
        <span id="subject-alert"></span>
        <textarea id="mail-message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
        <span id="message-alert"></span>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
        <span class="contact__form--alert-success" id="success-alert"></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function doRegister() {
  let checks = {
    name : document.getElementById("mail-name"),
    email : document.getElementById("mail-email"),
    subject : document.getElementById("mail-subject"),
    message : document.getElementById("mail-message")
  },
error = "";
  if (checks.name.value=="") {
    error += document.getElementById("name-alert").innerHTML+='<p>A name is required!</p>';
  }
  if (checks.subject.value=="") {
    error += document.getElementById("subject-alert").innerHTML+='<p>A subject is required!</p>';
  }
  if (checks.message.value=="") {
    error += document.getElementById("message-alert").innerHTML+='<p>A message is required!</p>';
  }
  let pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (!pattern.test(checks.email.value.toLowerCase())) {
    error += document.getElementById("email-alert").innerHTML+='<p>A valid email is required!</p>';
  }

// Ajax
if (error!="") {
    error="";
} else {
let data = new FormData();
for (let k in checks) {
  data.append(k, checks[k].value);
}
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "mail.php", true);
xhr.onload = function(){
        let res = JSON.parse(this.response);
        // SUCCESS!
  if (res.status) {
            document.getElementById("success-alert").innerHTML+='<p>Success!</p>';
  } else {
    // ERROR!
    error = "";
    for (let e of res['error']) {
      error += e + "\n";
    }
    alert(error);
  }
};
// SEND
xhr.send(data);
 }
 return false;
}
```

PHP:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$error = [];
$msg = '';
if ( array_key_exists( 'email', $_POST ) ) {
  date_default_timezone_set( 'Etc/UTC' );
  require 'mail/vendor/autoload.php';
  // Call super globals from the contact form names
  $email                        = $_POST['email'];
  $name                         = $_POST['name'];
  $subject          = $_POST['subject'];
  $message          = $_POST['message'];
  $mail             = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host       = 'mail.host.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
  $mail->Username   = 'name@host.com';
  $mail->Password   = 'password1';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Port       = 465;
  $mail->setFrom( 'name@host.com', 'New Message' );
  $mail->addAddress( 'somemail@mail.com' );
  if ($mail->addReplyTo($email, $name)) {
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->isHTML(false);
    $mail->Body = <<<EOT
Email: {$email}
Name: {$name}
Message: {$message}
EOT;
  }

// Check inputs
if ($name=="") {
    $error[] = "A name is required.";
}
if ($subject=="") {
    $error[] = "A subject is required.";
}
if ($message=="") {
    $error[] = "A message is required.";
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error[] = "A valid email is required.";
}

// JSON encode with a response
echo json_encode([
"status" => count($error)==0 ? 1 : 0,
"error" => $error
]);
 }
```

**Solution:**
the "send()" function was missing

```
if(empty($error)){
  if(!$mail->send()){
    $error[] = 'There was an error sending the mail. Please try again!';
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is all data received properly through the PHP script (which would make it a sole problem of PHP, no JS or AJAX involved)? Or is there already some data missing when debugging the PHP script (which probably makes it a JS / AJAX problem)?

Comment: Typically I work with wordpress that handles any debugging. This project is just on a plain local server, I still have yet to learn PHP tools properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP script doesn't send the mail because the `send()` function is not called, so after the validation, you should add something like:

```
if(empty($error)){
    if(!$mail->send()){
        $error[] = 'There was an error sending the mail. Please try again!';
    }
}

echo json_encode([
"status" => count($error)==0 ? 1 : 0,
"error" => $error
]);
```

This way you're sending the mail and, if there was a problem(`send()` returns `false`), an error is being added to your error array.

Comment: You know, I had a feeling it may have been the send function. The example code from PHPmailer's send function was preventing the json to run for whatever reason. This works perfectly, thanks! Also updating post with solution.